# Optimize the insert queries executed using Enterprise library

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have wrote an SQL SP to insert record in MSSQL table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAmazonIT
@BatchID INT,
@ITName NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_AmazonITMaster
    (Batch_Id,IT_Name)
    VALUES
    (@BatchID,@ITName)

    SELECT @@IDENTITY
END
```

I have around 15000 records to insert into DB,
I am calling the SP using enterprise library ExecuteScalar method...
while inserting data it takes lots n lots of time

C# Object Manager class is as follows:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    private string _key = "SqlDatabase"; 
    public SqlDatabase Db
    {
        get {
            if (ContextRepository.GetData(_key) == null)
            {
                ContextRepository.SetData(_key, DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase());
            }
            return (SqlDatabase)ContextRepository.GetData(_key);
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection Con
    {
        get {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PTMap"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}

public class AmazonITRepository:BaseRepository
{
    public int Add(AmazonIT it)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Db.ExecuteScalar("AddAmazonIT", it.Batch_Id, it.IT_Name));
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to optimize this?

Comment: You can't really "optimize" that particular bit of code and SP for inserting a single record, it will probably always be fairly slow to call it 15,000 times.  There might be more efficient way of inserting 15,000 records, but they would not use the code you have pasted.

Comment: You should take a look at using SQLBulkCopy to insert this number of rows. see http://elegantcode.com/2012/01/26/sqlbulkcopy-for-generic-listt-useful-for-entity-framework-nhibernate/